# "Иосифлянское" движение -- нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: орфография, словосочетания, кавычки, грамотная-речь, фразеология

Предложение: *Несколько священников примкнули к иосифлянскому движению.*

- Справка. Иосифлянское движение -- это движение РПЦ, возникшее в 1927 г., его участники отказались признавать нового митрополита Сергия (Страгородского) и его компромиссную с советской властью деятельность.
- В каких вообще случаях ставятся кавычки, когда речь идет о движениях социальных, религиозных, политических? Например, из Википедии: *В действиях «правых» оппозиционеров, часто называемых «непоминающими», нельзя обнаружить злонамеренных, исключительно личных мотивов.* То есть здесь религиозное движение будет оформляться кавычками: **движение "непоминающих".**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Религиозно-этические общественные течения пишутся без кавычек: *толстовство* (толстовское течение), *иосифлянство* (иосифлянское движение).

"Правые", "левые", "непоминающие" - условные названия, поэтому в кавычках, а иосифлянство, толстовство - общепринятое в общественной  литературе.